# iOS5 log out completely to test in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, ios5, in-app-purchase

I"m testing an in-app purchase using my iPhone on iOS5 but despite going to Settings > General > Store > Log out (as I've seen on many websites), I can only enter a password when prompted in my app. The username appears to be stuck as my primary Apple ID (used in the stores). Somewhere there must be a setting to sign out completely on the device, but I can't find it.

Anyone know how to fully sign out of the iTunes store on the device to test in app purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the App Store, scroll to the bottom in the "Featured"-pane. You should see your account there, click it and log out.

Comment: Thanks Emil, that's probably easier than what I ended up doing: logging out of iTunes on my computer and syncing my phone.

Comment: If this answer helped you, I would appreciate if you voted it up and accepted it as the best answer (click the ✔ next to the answer). Thank you!